# How to handle simultaneous React state updates with socket.io

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks, socket.io, use-state

Given the following React functional component:

```
const DataLog: FC = (props) => {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const pushEvent = (event: string) => {
    const updatedEvents = [...events];
    updatedEvents.push(event);
    setEvents([...updatedEvents]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket: Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents> = io(
      'http://localhost:9000'
    );

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Web socket connected');
    });

    socket.on('event1', (event: string) => {
      pushEvent(event);
    });

    socket.on('event2', (event: string) => {
      pushEvent(event);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {events.map((event: string, index: number) => {
        return <div key={index}>{event}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataLog;
```

I would like to update the `events` state variable each time an `event1` or `event2` message is received via the socket.io websocket connection. This works fine if the messages are coming in reasonably spaced out, but the issue arises when `event1` and `event2`, or multiple `event1` or `event2` messages come in very rapidly. The state update doesn't have enough time to complete before the next event is being processed resulting in the `events` array being overwritten by the last call to `setEvents`. Is there a way I can ensure each new message gets added to the `events` state object? Do I need to manually batch state updates? Is there another hook I can use to preserve state between updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pushEvent` function is a dependency of the `useEffect`, but isn't in it's dependencies array. This means that the updates use the initial function which points to the original empty `events` array.

You can add it as a dependency of `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your code
}, [pushEvent]);
```

However, this would cause the `useEffect` to be called on each render, since `pushEvent` is recreated on render, so you should probably avoid that.
Instead, set the state using [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to make the new state dependent on the previous one:

```
const DataLog: FC = (props) => {
  const [events, setEvents] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket: Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents> = io(
      'http://localhost:9000'
    );

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Web socket connected');
    });

    socket.on('event1', (event: string) => {
      setEvents(prev => [...prev, event]);
    });

    socket.on('event2', (event: string) => {
      setEvents(prev => [...prev, event]);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {events.map((event: string, index: number) => {
        return <div key={index}>{event}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The issue I see is that if multiple event1 or event2 events happen to enqueue state updates within a single render cycle then each processed update stomps the previous update. In effect, the last processed state update is the one seen on the subsequent render cycle.

## Solution

Use a [functional state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) update to correctly update from the previous state instead of using whatever may be closed over in the current callback/render scope. You can also move the `pushEvent` handler *into* the `useEffect` callback to remove it as an external dependency.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const socket: Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents> = io(
    'http://localhost:9000'
  );

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Web socket connected');
  });

  const pushEvent = (event: string) => {
    setEvents(events => [...events, event]); // functional update
  };

  socket.on('event1', (event: string) => {
    pushEvent(event);
  });

  socket.on('event2', (event: string) => {
    pushEvent(event);
  });
}, []);
```